# HTML Canvas draw a circle on mouse click and drag it untill the required radius is obtained

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Im new to canvas and i was playing around with it.

I wanted to draw a circle on mouse click and radius of circle should be decided by mouse drag (**similar to drawing circle in Paint in windows** )

i have tried creating a circle but struck doing this
my code

```
<html>

    <head>

    </head>

    <body style="margin:0">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid"></canvas>

    <script>

    var canvas=document.getElementById('canvas');
    var context=canvas.getContext('2d');
    var radius=50;

    var putPoint = function(e){
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(e.clientX, e.clientY, radius, 0, Math.PI*2);
        context.fill();
    }
         canvas.addEventListener('mousedown',putPoint);

    </script>
    </body>

    </html>﻿
```

my code in plunker 
http://plnkr.co/edit/DPa9km1hHAAsCBCbnGvB?p=preview

I would be happy if someone help me out

Thanks in advance

Comment: you want to circle instead of a disk, that's it? you want one? many? very unclear

Comment: I wanted a circle and the circle is drawn on click and and the radius is drawn by dragging the circle....similar to Microsoft paint..where we drag and create circle

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the general ideia is that you have to take 2 points, the one there circle center will be (this is where the user presses the mouse), and the current point, where the mouse is moving

the distance between the 2 points will be the radius, and is given by the Pythagorean theorem `h^2 = c^2 + c^2` so:

- onmousedown save that point as center
- omousemove calculate the distance to center and use as radius
- omouseup stop the operation/animation

here is some sample code, modify to your needs

```
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body style="margin:0">
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid"></canvas>

<script>

var canvas=document.getElementById('canvas');
var context=canvas.getContext('2d');
var radius=50;
var nStartX = 0;
var nStartY = 0;
var bIsDrawing = false;
var putPoint = function(e){
  nStartX = e.clientX;nStartY = e.clientY;
  bIsDrawing = true;
  radius = 0;
}
var drawPoint = function(e){
  if(!bIsDrawing)
    return;
  var nDeltaX = nStartX - e.clientX;
  var nDeltaY = nStartY - e.clientY;
  radius = Math.sqrt(nDeltaX * nDeltaX + nDeltaY * nDeltaY)
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(nStartX, nStartY, radius, 0, Math.PI*2);
  context.fill();
}
var stopPoint = function(e){
  bIsDrawing = false;
}
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown',putPoint);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',drawPoint);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup',stopPoint);

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm downvoting this answer because it's a code dump.  Add some explanation so OP and other visitors can learn from what's going on and I'll switch that to an upvote.